# Can we specify the CSRF token expiry timeout?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-rest

I am using spring security and Java configurations in my project.

The Java configurations for spring security by default have csrf enabled.

Is it possible to set the timeout after which the csrf token expires? This was a requirement to specify the timeout for the token based application.

After going through some blogs and articles, I noticed that the behavior of csrf token is unpredictable to make it more secured.

Here is a sample code for configuring spring security.

```
@Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http.sessionManagement().maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login-expired.html").and().and()
                .authorizeRequests().antMatchers("/superadmin/**").access("hasRole('ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN')").and()
                .formLogin().loginPage("/signin.html").permitAll().failureUrl("/login-failed.html").permitAll()
                .and().exceptionHandling().accessDeniedPage("/403").and().logout().permitAll().and()
                .exceptionHandling().and().logout().logoutSuccessUrl("/logout.html").permitAll().and()
    }
```

If there is some way by which I can set up the timeout that would save me a lot of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See [Spring Security Reference](http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-security/4.1.x/reference/htmlsingle/#csrf-timeouts):

> One issue is that the expected CSRF token is stored in the HttpSession, so as soon as the HttpSession expires your configured `AccessDeniedHandler` will receive a InvalidCsrfTokenException.

That means, you could change the session timeout in your `web.xml` to expire the CSRF token, see for example [WebLogic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs81/webapp/web_xml.html#1017275):

> `<session-timeout>` | optional | The number of minutes after which sessions in this Web application expire

Another way is to write your own [`CsrfTokenRepository`](http://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/current/apidocs/org/springframework/security/web/csrf/CsrfTokenRepository.html):

> An API to allow changing the method in which the expected `CsrfToken` is associated to the `HttpServletRequest`. For example, it may be stored in `HttpSession`.