# CSRF Token unexpectedly expires

Tags: spring-boot, tomcat

I have an app built with Spring Boot, it's using Apache Tomcat 8.5.53.

It all works fine, but sometimes my users get the following message:

`HTTP Status 403 - ForbiddenType Status ReportMessage Invalid CSRF Token '1423gi43-3452-65t3-cg8d-21a75cd7gc3x' was found on the request parameter '_csrf' or header 'X-CSRF-TOKEN'`

Then they refresh the page, login and it all works fine.

This doesn't always happen, and it doesn't happen for the same request. My users perform normally other operations before they see this message. However, it happens most of the time on `post` or `patch` requests.

I have seen issues on stackoverflow where token is null, but in my case it randomly expires.

I don't want to remove the token.

Has anyone experienced (and hopefully solved) this issue before?

Comment: Any idea after how much time they get this? See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39754419/can-we-specify-the-csrf-token-expiry-timeout where is explained that the token might become invalid after a certain time.

Comment: Do you have large numbers of links being created on each page? The CSRF token cache is per-user, stored in the session. But it's length is finite. If you generate some large number of links, each one will get a different token stored in that cache. If you overflow the cache, the oldest tokens expire immediately, possibly before they "should".

Comment: @WimDeblauwe they are valid for two hours. Do you know if, generally speaking, they only get refreshed if there's a post request, or get request also works fine?

Comment: @ChristopherSchultz, thank you, I will look into it

Comment: CSRF tokens are normally not used for GET requests.

Comment: @WimDeblauwe CSRF tokens are required to secure any state-changing request. There are *many* `GET` requests that change application state. Tomcat's implementation of the `CsrfPreventionFilter` will not *check* a `GET`-request's nonce (I'm going to have to check on why that is), but it *will* generate a new nonce for each request, whether the application ends up using it or not. So a large number of `GET` requests can end up overflowing the cache and prematurely-expiring some tokens.

Comment: I was mis-reading the Tomcat code: the `CsrfPreventionFilter` does indeed protect `GET` requests. It will allow token-less `GET` requests to certain "entry point" URLs (e.g. the "home page" of the application), otherwise it would not be possible to ever access the application :)